# How to pass dictionary type object in url?

Tags: python, flask

I am learning flask. I trying to use request.args.get(). I am confused about how to make a url request containing dictionary object

here is my code. I want to send e url request to /hello like "text":"Hello World"

```py
@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    text = request.args.get("text",default="Hello World",type=str)
    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to hit this endpoint from a browser, passing a text argument, try a URL like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello?text=Fahad
```

Answer (score 0):

got the answer 
It would be

hello?key=value

Comment: Given the code above, you need `text=value`, not `key=value`.

Comment: I got it
I reffered to text as a key